# How to make table with rowspan

Tags: html

I want to make table like this. A has 5row and B has 2.5row. I show another question about rowspan vlaue have to be integer. So I tried to revise totalrow is 6 and A is 6row , B is 3row, C is 1row and one is 2row. But I can't do like this image. If you can solve it, please talk to me.

[image]

Comment: Have you attempted to write any markup for this yet?  Please share your efforts so far and we can help from there

Comment: Please read  the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Just copy/pasting your assignments will not win you any friends.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a basic example for you.  You add the rowspan to the *TD* Tag and then on the subsequent rows, you have 1 less *TD* tag

```css
table, tr, td { border:1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Row Span 2</td>
    <td>Normal Column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Normal Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT - Taking into account the fact that column B is 2.5 rows tall, and after review of the other answer, here is complete method, which uses both an extra table and rowspan

```css
table, tr, td { border:1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <table border=1 width=100% height=100%>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="5">A</td>
            <td rowspan="5" height=100%>
            <table border=1 width=100% height="100%">
              <tr>
                <td>B1</td>                
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td>B2</td>
              </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>C1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```